# Как подключить класс Request в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, framework, controller

Люди, разбирающиеся в Laravel помогите плиз с классом Request, вроде запросил не обертку, а Illuminate/Http/Request, phpstorm выдает, что класс request is undefined classm, в чем может быть проблема?

```
<?php                                                                       

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;                                        

use App\User;                                                               
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;                                        
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;                              
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;                                   
use Illuminate\Http\Request;                                                


class RegisterController extends Controller                                 

{                                                                           
    /*                                                                      
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller                                                   
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                                                                       
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to   
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.     
    |                                                                       
    */                                                                      

    use RegistersUsers;                                                     

    /**                                                                     
     * Where to redirect users after registration.                          
     *                                                                      
     * @var string                                                          
     */                                                                     
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';                                        

    /**                                                                     
     * Create a new controller instance.                                    
     *                                                                      
     * @return void                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function __construct()                                           
    {                                                                       
        $this->middleware('guest');                                         
    }                                                                       
    /**                                                                     
    * @param Request $request                                               
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirect
    */                                                                      

    public function register( Request $request)                             
    {                                                                       
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();                      

        /**event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));   

        $this->guard()->login($user);*/                                     
        $email = $request->input('email');                                  
        $password = $request->input('password');                            
        $isAuth = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;                 
        $biguser = $this->create(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password]); 

        if(!($biguser instanceof User)){                                    
            return back()->with('error', 'thats it');                       
        }                                                                   
        if($isAuth){                                                        

            $this->guard()->login($biguser);                                
        }                                                                   

       return redirect (route('account'));                                  

    }                                                                       

    /**                                                                     
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.                
     *                                                                      
     * @param  array  $data                                                 
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator                   
     */                                                                     
    protected function validator(array $data)                               
    {                                                                       
        return Validator::make($data, [                                     
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',        
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',                
        ]);                                                                 
    }                                                                       

    /**                                                                     
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.               
     *                                                                      
     * @param  array  $data                                                 
     * @return \App\User                                                    
     */                                                                     
    protected function create(array $data)                                  
    {                                                                       
        return User::create([                                               
            'email' => $data['email'],                                      
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),                        
        ]);                                                                 
    }                                                                       
}
```

Comment: `composer dumpautoload` первым делом попробуй

Comment: Попробовал, все равно в request ничего не приходит, dd($request) ничего не выводит

Comment: тогда не парься и переустанови laravel по гайду из документации

Comment: Хорошо, попробую заново все